# If samsara exist then why Vishnu needs to take avatar to defeat adharma?

Tags: avatars, samsara

if samsara exist then why god needs to take avatar to defeat Evil?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please give clarity to question

Answer (score 2):

**ऋत ṛta**, is the Vedic notion of the cosmic order, inevitably fundamental  for the existence and sustenance of the manifestated universe .

The inextricable connection between the ethics of nature and the phisical universe is observed via the order that prexist ,such as biological processes, sunrise, planetary movement, water resources etc. (
see **Rigveda 1.105.12**.) which proves that interdependence in the grand order exist, and  the truth of cosmic harmony.

Dharm(a) is the antecedent of rta. (Dharayati iti Dharmaha), one that upholds.(social order)

Samsara is the flux  of sukh(a) and/or dukh(a) Enjoyed or Endured perpetually,
(Only texts on Brahma Vidhya reason the cause/nature of samsara, show the path to free oneself from its limitations.)

But the rhythm of samsara, is impacted  by the social order (upheld by dharma).  Avathara of the Ishwara(supreme) sets this order right incase of imbalance.In this way the Avatara is connected to samsara.
(as any Jiva has to inevitably engage with this world to pursue samsara)

Bhagavad Gita puts forth a lot of emphasis on **lokasangraha**(welfare of common good,), even attributes it as a reason for  jnani karma and kamayogis karma.

Avatar(a) unlike Jiva is not constrained by the locus of samsara.Avatara manifests by 'divine will' to set right the social order (establish dharma), against a Jiva born due to karma to experience samsara.

Bhagavad Gita 4.6

> ajo ’pi sannavyayātmā bhūtānām īśhvaro ’pi san
> prakṛitiṁ svām adhiṣhṭhāya sambhavāmyātma-māyayā

> Although I am unborn, the Lord of all living entities, and have an imperishable nature, yet I appear in this world by virtue of Yogmaya, My divine power.(English Translation by Swami Mukundananda)

Vedas view -

Brihadaaranyaka Upanishad 2.3.1

> dve vāva brahmaṇo rūpe—mūrtaṃ caivāmūrtaṃ ca, martyaṃ cāmṛtaṃ ca, sthitaṃ ca yacca, sacca, tyacca || 1 ||

> Brahman has but two forms—gross and subtle, mortal and immortal, limited and unlimited, defined and undefined.(courtesy wisdom lib)

Above is the mention of saguna Brahman and nirguna brahman. in Vedas

,Avataras are divine manifesation, aspect of Saguna Brahman beyond the blemishes of gunas.

Bhagavad Gita 4.7

> yadā yadā hi dharmasya glānir bhavati bhārata
> abhyutthānam adharmasya tadātmānaṁ sṛijāmyaham

> Whenever there is a decline in righteousness and an increase in unrighteousness, O Arjun, at that time I manifest Myself on earth.(English Translation by Swami Mukundananda)

Bhagavad Gita 4.8

> paritrāṇāya sādhūnāṁ vināśhāya cha duṣhkṛitām
> dharma-sansthāpanārthāya sambhavāmi yuge yuge

> To protect the righteous, to annihilate the wicked, and to reestablish the principles of dharma I appear on this earth, age after age
> (English Translation by Swami Mukundananda)

Bhagavad gita 9.11

> avajānanti māṁ mūḍhā mānuṣhīṁ tanum āśhritam
> paraṁ bhāvam ajānanto mama bhūta-maheśhvaram

> When I descend in My personal form deluded persons are unable to recognize Me. They do not know the divinity of My personality, as the Supreme Lord of all beings.(English Translation by Swami Mukundananda)